# gcc bug in condition variable::wait_for

Tags: c++, gcc

Seems there is a bug in gcc's `std::condition_variable::cv.wait_for()`.

If the system time change during the wait, it will return after the wrong period.

Most often - it just doesn't return if the time is moved to the past, or awakes immediately if time moves to the future.

I think the cause is that it uses system clock instead if steady_clock (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/condition_variable#L67).

Did anybody come across this issue ? what could be a workaround ?

Comment: "what could be a workaround ?" - Don't change the system time ;-)

Comment: system time is expected to be changed/adjusted occasionally on any normal system.

Comment: Sure. Adjusted *slightly*. But, in any case, you asked for workarounds, and *not* adjusting the system time *is* a valid workaround.

Comment: @JesperJuhl SMITH: Doctor, it hurts when I do this. DALE: Don't do that.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the standard agrees with you that the clock used should be `std::chrono::steady_clock`.

> § 30.5.1
>
> 39. Effects: as if
>     `return wait_until(lock, chrono::steady_clock::now() + rel_time, std::move(pred));`

This bug also appears to be [tracked](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41861) by the GCC folks already.

As for fixes/workarounds you could:

- Submit a fix to `libstdc++`
- [Use libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#using-libc-with-gcc), which [appears to get it right](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/36bf18fc64b531fd994000cee56ff7c7d2181d13/include/condition_variable#L248).

Comment: Thanks for the links. The bug tracking link is really interesting read. This bug is 9 years old already..